# How can I mark a global variable as an offset using IDAPython?

Tags: ida, idapython

I have a four byte global variable that is a pointer to some other data. How can I mark this to be an offset (like pressing `o`) using IDAPython?

```
.text:00436FF3      dd 43702Ch
```

`ida_offset.op_offset_ex` ([ref](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/)) seems close to what I want, but is intended for marking instruction operand types, not global variables.

Comment: It should work with globals too. Just use operand number 0.

Comment: Thanks, @ws! I've updated the post with an answer below, but I'm afraid this steals your rep. If you repaste the same (or similar content), I'll remove my answer and accept yours. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to see you on this SE site. I admire your RCE and forensics related work.

Answer (score 2):

Following the advice of [@ws](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17798/how-can-i-mark-a-global-variable-as-an-offset-using-idapython?noredirect=1#comment28001_17798), you can use operand number 0 with `ida_offset.op_offset(ea, n, type, target=BADADDR, base=0, tdelta=0)`.

For example:

```
ida_offset.op_offset(0x436FF3, 0, idc.REF_OFF32)
```

Note: `idc.OpOffset` did not work consistently for me, while `ida_offset.op_offset` did. So, you may want to prefer the later routine.